# Код не компилируется, а выдает страницу с просто с файлами моего кода

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vue3

скачал код проекта по vue3 на gitHub, что бы разобраться в коде. Открыл его через VS CODE, проверил наличие node, запустил проект, и в браузере мне открылась страница просто с папками проекта. Подскажите пожалуйста, почему код не компилируется. Спасибо большое. [image: Получившийся результат] [image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

На скриншоте виден номер порта: 5500. Это порт, который по умолчанию использует расширение GoLive для VS Code. GoLive - это очень простой веб сервер, котрый не имеет никакого отношения к Ноде.

Как я помню, Нода обычно вешается на порт 3000. Попробуйте в браузере поменять номер порта. Убедитесь также, что нода запущена в консоли.

Дополняю ответ.

Прошу прощенния, перепутал Vue с реактом. Это у него сервер разработки на 3000 порту, у Vue - на 8080.

Короткий  ответ: в консоли VS Code надо написать команду `npm run serve`, в результате запустится "сервер разработки" на node, и при запуске он **напишет в консоли** что нужно зайти по адресу `http://localhost:8080/`:

[image: Запуск проекта из консольки VS Code]

Заходим по этому адресу, видим, что всё на месте:
[image: Что видно в браузере]

Теперь - как я разобрался.

Самым информативным оказался скриншот с картинкой VS Code с открытым проектом.

Я нашел vue - компонент, который показан на картинке.

Попробовал повторить шаги.

Клонирую себе репозиторий
https://github.com/jonbackus/vue3-accessible-accordion

Склонировал.

Студия предложила мне поставить расширение для Vue, согласился.

Вижу по коду, что вроде бы это законченый пример.
Иду читать, как такие примеры запускать.
Нахожу:
https://docs.kontent.ai/tutorials/develop-apps/get-started/run-sample-app?tech=javascript

В принципе, дальше я шел по этой инструкции:
запускаем `npm install`, смотрим, как нода ставит себе полмира

Запускаем `npm run serve` - любуемся на работу компонента.

Встал вопрос: можно ли VS Code обучить делать то же самое по наждатию F5. Думаю, что нужно ей сделать default task, но еще не пробовал.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за совет, я проверил наличие ноды еще раз(Скриншот2) и поменял порт на 3000, но к сожалению вообще выдало ошибку(Скриншот3). Подскажите пожалуйста, может быть проблема в несовместимости кода и новой версии редактора? Скриншоты загружу в основной вопрос, а то тут нельзя вставлять фото...

Comment: Спасибо огромные вам, что нашли этот проект, теперь у меня тоже запустилось, то что у вас на втором скриншоте, но вам не кажется что он запустился не весь, там вроде другой должен быть результат, а не поле для ввода, две кнопки и две строчки?

Comment: Странно, а как это выглядит у Вас? я посмотрел в файл vue3-accessible-accordion/src/App.vue - и вижу в нём те же самые слова, как и на моём скриншоте. То есть, эти вот две кнопки и два поля ввода - это вроде как и есть "демо акордеона". Было бы интересно увидеть, что это выглядит как то по другому. Если у Вас получится - напишите, или приложите скриншот?

Answer (score 0):

1. Если проект ни разу не собирали, то попробуйте для начала выполнить сборку командой `npm run build`
2. Что бы запустить среду разработки vue-cli на конкретном порту, надо указать этот порт вручную в консоли командой `npm run serve -- --port 3000`, где 3000 и есть номер порта.
3. В браузере открываем адрес: `localhost:3000`, где "3000" это указанный порт из пункта 2.

PS: Если пункт 2 не получится, то скиньте скриншот консоли, после выполнения команды.

Comment: Пожалуйста. Если данный ответ решил вашу проблему, от отметьте его как решение.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, теперь у меня запустилось, благодарю, теперь я буду знать что проблема в сборке и в номере порта.